# mysqldump via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that gets passed the MySQL connection details of a remote server and I want it to execute a `mysqldump` command. To do this I'm using the php `exec()` function:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysql-user -h 123.145.167.189 -pmysql-pass database_name > /path-to-export/file.sql", $output);
?>
```

When the right login details are passed to it, it'll work absolutely fine.
However, I'm having trouble checking *if* it executes as expected and if it doesn't finding out why not.
The `$output` array returns as empty, whereas if I run the command directly on the command line a message is printed out telling me the login failed. I want to capture such error messages and display them. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should check the third parameter of **exec** function: `&$return_var`.

```
$return_var = NULL;
$output = NULL;
$command = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysql-user -h 123.145.167.189 -pmysql-pass database_name > /path-to-export/file.sql";
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

By convention in Unix a **process returns anything other than 0 when something goes wrong**.

And so you can:

```
if($return_var) { /* there was an error code: $return_var, see the $output */ }
```

Comment: here's the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and i think its better to say it this way: "By convention in Unix a process returns anything other than 0 when something goes wrong" :)

Comment: Is there any way to know what each value of $return_var means so I can translate it to a meaningful error message? Would guess it's different for each command.

Comment: if $return_var is not equal to zero, the $output must have error code, because programs write error to stderr which different than stdout that you redirected to a file. 'if($return_var) { die($output); }'

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Yes, `$return_var` returns as a positive integer and I'm now using that to determine if the command executed successfully or if something went wrong which at least gives us some idea.  However, with MySQLdump (have not yet noticed it with other commands we're running in the same way) `$output` is an empty array. When running the exact same command directly on the command line it gives us a relevant error telling us what permission is wrong or missing.

Comment: @RossMcLellan: Check this [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/249853/does-mysqldump-return-a-status)

Answer (score 8):

The solution I found is to run the command in a sub-shell and then output the `stderr` to `stdout` (`2>&1`). This way, the `$output` variable is populated with the error message (if any).

i.e. :

```
exec("(mysqldump -uroot -p123456 my_database table_name > /path/to/dump.sql) 2>&1", $output, $exit_status);

var_dump($exit_status); // (int) The exit status of the command (0 for success, > 0 for errors)
echo "<br />";
var_dump($output); // (array) If exit status != 0 this will handle the error message.
```

Results :

> int(6)
>
> array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "table_name"" }

Hope it helps !

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the correct answer.  Simple, direct code that yields the information needed!

Answer (score 4):

Because this line redirect the stdout output `> /path-to-export/file.sql`
try this,

```
<?php 
exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysql-user -h 123.145.167.189 -pmysql-pass database_name", $output);
/* $output will have sql backup, then save file with these codes */
$h=fopen("/path-to-export/file.sql", "w+");
fputs($h, $output);
fclose($h);
?>
```

Comment: a bit far fetched if you ask me

Comment: My native language is Turkish which is far away from English, that's what prevent me from writing powerful answers. As he says the $output is empty, then i said the reason that why its empty. $output is stdout and if he use ">" (which means redirect stdout to file) he will not have output, and that's totally logical. However there is stderr too, if there is an error $output will error in this case, even he redirected stdout to file. p.s. he asked $output

Comment: yes i completely agree, i just meant there is a simpler way to do this :)

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea. Unfortunately just tested it and even without the `> /path-to-export/file.sql` redirecting the output it doesn't return the error message in the `$output` variable.

Comment: $output only will have the output that mysqldump gives, not a special message. If you want to use my solution, you must check the $output for a special error. If there is a error, mysqldump would return a line indicating there is a error. You need to parse this string. In other solution, if $return_var is not equal 0, the output would only have stderr which means error description.

Comment: Yes, `stdout` has been redirected to the file but OP is expecting `stderr` from the command which `exec` can't fetch.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the exact same solution, and I remembered I'd already solved this a couple of years ago, but forgotten about it.

As this page is high in Google for the question, here's how I did it:

```
<?php
define("BACKUP_PATH", "/full/path/to/backup/folder/with/trailing/slash/");

$server_name   = "your.server.here";
$username      = "your_username";
$password      = "your_password";
$database_name = "your_database_name";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --hex-blob --routines --skip-lock-tables --log-error=mysqldump_error.log -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

$arr_out = array();
unset($return);

exec($cmd, $arr_out, $return);

if($return !== 0) {
    echo "mysqldump for {$server_name} : {$database_name} failed with a return code of {$return}\n\n";
    echo "Error message was:\n";
    $file = escapeshellarg("mysqldump_error.log");
    $message = `tail -n 1 $file`;
    echo "- $message\n\n";
}
?>
```

It's the *--log-error=[/path/to/error/log/file]* part of mysqldump that I always forget about!

Comment: I tried this answer but couldn't get it to work. I'm running a local WAMP server and the directory I'm running in is `www/test/index.php`. I've set `BACKUP_PATH` to "/test/" and I created a file called "mysqlydump_error.log" and placed it within the "test" directory. I'm getting the error message, but it does not display an error and the error log is also empty. I've made sure that my user has permissions too. Help?

Comment: Now I can get a backup file to appear, but it's blank.

Comment: @AndrewFox, [Rick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4392819/rick) says 'Shouldn't the path be /www/test/ or possibly /var/www/test/ depending on your configuration? Do a pwd from the directory you want the log file placed and put that in with a trailing slash.'

Comment: I've got the paths correct now as the file is appearing as expected, but the file is empty.

Comment: I used above solution in codeigniter but getting error as mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Answer (score 1):

As `exec()` is fetching just `stdout` which is redirected to the file, we have partial or missing result in the file and we don't know why. We have to get message from `stderr` and `exec()` can't do that. There are several solutions, all has been already found so this is just a summary.

1. [Solution from Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482379/904846): log errors from `mysqldump` and handle them separately (can't apply for every command).
2. Redirect outputs to separate files, i.e. `mysqldump ... 2> error.log 1> dump.sql` and read the error log separately as in previous solution.
3. [Solution from JazZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018165/904846): write the dump as a subshell and redirect stderr of the subshell to stdout which can php `exec()` put in the `$output` variable.
4. [Solution from Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320835/904846): better be using `proc_open()` instead of `exec()` because we can get `stdout` and `stderr` separately (directly from pipes).

Answer (score -1):

write below code to get the database export in .sql file.

```
<?php exec('mysqldump --user=name_user --password=password_enter --host=localhost database_name > filenameofsql.sql'); ?>
```