# mysqldump Error 1045 Access denied despite correct passwords etc

Tags: mysql, localhost, access-denied, mysql-error-1045, windows-xp-sp3

This is a tricky one, I have the following output:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

When attempting to export my database with `mysqldump` on Windows XP. The username is root, the password is correct and contains only alphanumeric characters. I have tried different cases, with/without quotes, specifying using `-u` and `-p`, specifying using `--user=` and `--password=` and other methods of specifying user/passwords etc, specifying the host (it's all local) and even specifying the database using `--databases` instead of just blank.  The error is always the same when using a password and always the same except the "NO" message when without.  I have tried many fixes found through searches with no success.  One fix suggested inspecting mysql.conf, but the Windows build doesn't seem to have one.  The credentials (and indeed commandline parameters) work perfectly with mysql.exe - this problem only seems to be affecting mysqldump.exe.

Comment: did you try with `-p` option without applying the password? then you should be prompted for the password.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database with mysql client using the same credentials?

Comment: Same credentials, identical login part of the command-line to that used with mysql.exe.  password is specified correctly as it works with mysql.exe.

Comment: Check the password specified, and try to add --host option.

Comment: Tried using `-h`, that didn't work.  The password is correct as it's the same as that used for MySQL.exe and that works perfectly!

Comment: Have you connected as 'root'@'localhost' and specified --host=localhost? Check carefully if this user with specified password exists.

Comment: Tried that and the root password definitely exists as I can use the same credentials to log into mysql.exe perfectly.

Comment: It is very strange. If you can connect using mysql.exe, then you can connect from mysqldump.exe. Try another MySQL tool/client.

Comment: I know that's how it should be but for some reason mysql.exe works and mysqldump.exe doesn't!  I know I'm not the only person that has experienced something like this too, it's just that none of the fixes that worked for them work for me...

Comment: Anyone know if there's any way to create the dumpfile text from within MySQL itself?  If so, I could probably just pipe the output from that instead...

Comment: @Devart Is there a 3rd-party MySQL Dump utility then?  A quick Google doesn't seem to find any evidence of one.

Comment: Yes there is, for example you can use [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) - Backup feature, command line is supported.

Comment: That works great, thanks!  I'd still like to get this sorted but at least it's less desperate now.  :D

Comment: I think it is -P option that gives port of mysql instance... so this answer is great: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27288057/11374

Comment: Got exec error message to display in PHP via: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21482379/1673876 mysqldump was giving error 1045 when using a username and password: 'user'@'localhost' denied even though 127.0.0.1 was specified as host name. The problem seems to be with the host specified in the phpMyAdmin user privileges table. Experiment with 127.0.0.1, localhost, % as user host privileges. When I use the user root with no password it works fine, so the issue seems to be with the way phpMyAdmin and mysqldump handle the host specified.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Also see [How to have MySQL entitle the root user?](http://superuser.com/q/1060360) on Super User. It attempts to avoid resetting passwords.

Comment: @jww dba.stackexchange.com is the right place I reckon.

Answer (score 85):

This worked for me

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydbscheme > mydbscheme_dump.sql
```

after issuing the command it asks for a password:

```
Enter password:
```

entering the password will make the dump file.

Comment: Hi. This is incredibly strange behavior of MySQL. I check various versions by some hours, and variant --password='<mypassword>', where <mypassword> is my password - work for me! But -p='...' or --password=<mypassword> - NOT working! SIC! Single quotes around password is required!!

Comment: @S.H. It depends if you have any special characters in your password, like ( or )

Comment: to  Boris Pavlović: thank you for your comment. But, in my case I use only alphabetical and numbers chars in password. May be, ssh-terminal and other environment properties affects?

Answer (score 42):

If you're able to connect to the database using mysql, but you get an error for mysqldump, then the problem may be that you lack privileges to lock the table.

Try the --single-transaction option in that case.

```
mysqldump -h database.example.com -u mydbuser -p mydatabase --single-transaction  > /home/mylinuxuser/mydatabase.sql
```

Comment: In above don't use space between -p switch and actual db password e.g.  
`mysqldump -h database.example.com -u mydbuser -p'mydatabase' --single-transaction > /home/mylinuxuser/mydatabase.sql`  
Note: use the single quotes if the password contain special characters $()# etc.

Comment: @NaveedAnwar mydatabase is the database being dumped, not the password.

Comment: This worked for me. The original error message said, "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when using LOCK TABLES."

Answer (score 28):

Try to remove the space when using the -p-option. This works for my OSX and Linux mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword ...
```

Comment: I believe this should be marked the correct answer

Comment: Yes, this helped

Answer (score 21):

The access being denied is probably to the Windows file system not to the MySQL database; try redirecting the output file to a location where your account is allowed to create files.

Comment: This saved me. Default win 7 user has not enough rights to write in bin folder !

Comment: Spot on. When I changed the redirection to a different folder it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You need to put backslashes in your password that contain shell metacharacters, such as !#'"`&;

Comment: This got me on the right track, I had a hash symbol in my password. Backslash didn't do it for me, but I put my password in single quotes and all good.

Answer (score 12):

Don't enter the password with command. Just enter,

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <db_name> > <backup_file>.sql
```

Then you will get a prompt to enter password.

Answer (score 8):

Access dined problem solved when I run command prompt in `Administrator` mode.

Go to `Start-> All Programs -> Accessories` right click on `Command Prompt` clickc on `Run as..` Select `The Following User` select `administrator username` from select option enter password if any click `OK` button.

**Example 1:** For entire database backup in mysql using command prompt.

**In Windows 7 and 8**

```
C:\Program Files <x86>>\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqldump test -u root -p >testDB.sql
Enter Password: *********
```

**In Windows xp**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqldump test -u root -p >testDB.sql
Enter Password: *********
```

It asks password for credentials enter password and click on Enter button.

**Example 2:** For specific table backup / dump in mysql using command prompt.

**In Windows 7 and 8**

```
C:\Program Files <x86>>\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqldump test -u root -p images>testDB_Images.sql
Enter Password: *********
```

**In Windows xp**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqldump test -u root -p images>testDB_Images.sql
Enter Password: *********
```

Dumpt file will be created under folder

**In windows xp**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
```

**In windows 7 and 8**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin`

**Note:** Check MySQL installation folder in Windows 7, 8 while run in command prompt. If `MySQLWorkbench` is 32 bit version it is installed in `Program Files (x86)` folder other wise `Program Files` folder.

Answer (score 7):

Put The `GRANT` privileges:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me. I had to replace % with localhost.

Comment: Worked for me. GRANT as,                                                              GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';  followed by mysqldump as below,     mysqldump --socket=$HOME/apps/mariadb/mysql.sock -u username -p mydb --single-transaction > db_backup.sql

Comment: IDENTIFIED BY 'password' doesn't work for server version 8

Answer (score 6):

mysqldump -h hostname -u username -P port -B database --no-create-info -p > output.sql

I think you should specify the args

Comment: port is the key trick I think. because mysqldump is working directly on the default port... :) thanks

Comment: There was another mysqld sneakily occypying port 3306 for me, and mysqldump was trying to access that one rather than the one from its own installation

Answer (score 5):

Putting -p as the first option worked for me on Windows Server 2012R2 (in cmd.exe as Admin).

```
mysqldump.exe –p --user=root  --databases DBname --result-file=C:\DBname.sql
```

Comment: OMG, so much time wasted, but it was so simple...
Thanks Hank!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Problem was that I copied this command from internet

```
mysqldump –u <user_name> –p <db_name> > db.sql
```

and Ubuntu didn't understand the "-" symbol because difference of encoding.
So, solution was to remove this symbol and write by myself.

Answer (score 3):

Doing without the `-u` and `-p` worked for me (when I was logged in as root):

```
mysqldump --opt mydbname > mydbname.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this after a fresh install of MySQL 5.6.16.

Oddly, it works *without* the password specified or flagged:

`mysqldump -u root myschema mytable > dump.sql`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I could access correctly with `mysql.exe` but not with `mysqldump.exe`.

The problem was the port for my connection was not the default one (3306) and I had to put the mysqldump port work with (-P3307)

`mysqldump -u root -p -P3307 my_database > /path/backup_database`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, for 30min! I found that I was using `_p` instead of `-p`, the terminal font confused me!

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump -u (user) -p(passwd) -h (host_or_IP) database_to_backup > backup_file.sql

example:

mysqldump -u god -pheaven -h 10.0.10.10 accounting > accounting_20141209.sql

this would create sql backup file for the accounting database on server 10.0.10.10.  Sometimes your error is seen when localhost is not in config.  Designating ip of server may help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the single ticks after the password flag:

```
--password=mypassword
```

and **NOT**

```
--password='mypassword'
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql replies with Access Denied with correct credentials when the mysql account has `REQUIRE SSL` on

The `ssl_ca` file (at a minimum) had to be provided in the connection paramiters.

Additional ssl parameters might be required and are documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connection-options.html

---

Also posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626932/1695680

Answer (score 1):

For MAMP PRO users (or anyone who's mysql is in a weird location) be prepared to specify the mysql full path from the boonies and also specify full path to your user local folder where you want to dump the file or you'll get the "permission denied error"..

Following worked for me after 3 hours of research:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump  -u root -proot YOUR_DB > /Users/YOUR_USER/yourdump2.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me

```
mysqldump -h hostname.com -u username -p'password' database > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

In Past same problem occurred to me after I copied the mysqldump statement from a MS Word file.

But When typing the statement directly, everything worked fine.

In hex editor the "-" of the not working statement was represented by the unicode char e2 80 93  (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)

In sort, type password directly and check the copy paste code as the uni-code (or other encoding) strings might cause an issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for last 2 days. Tried bunch of things. Nothing worked.
But this did work:
Create another user. Grant it everything.
`mysqldump -u new_user db_name > db_name.sql`    //no error

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a running apache process acessing the MYSQL causing this error. So I suggest to ensure that all processes which might interact with the DB are shutdown beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that there were views that had a bad "DEFINER", which is the user that defined the view. The DEFINER used in the view had been removed some time ago as being "root from some random workstation".

Check whether there might be a problem by running:

```
USE information_schema; 
SELECT DEFINER, SECURITY_TYPE FROM views;
```

I modified the DEFINER (actually, set the DEFINER to `root@localhost` and the SQL SECURITY value to `INVOKER` so the view is executed with the permissions of the invoking user instead of the defining user, which actually makes more sense) using [ALTER VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-view.html).

This is tricky as you have to construct the appropriate `ALTER VIEW` statement from `information_schema.views`, so check:

- [Modify DEFINER on many
  views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views)
- [MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I omitted the password.

So `mysqldump -u user dbname > dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Tried most of the above with no joy.
Looking at my password, it had characters that might confuse a parser. I wrapped the password in quotes and the error was resolved.
-p"a:@#$%^&+6>&FAEH"

Using 8.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a mysql data dump, you can use mysqldump command. Following command will create a sql file called xxx.sql at the same location from where this command is run. xxx.sql will have all the necessary sqls to replicate exactly same db schema in any other mysql database.

Command is : mysqldump -u root -p**password** --databases ***database Name you want to import*** > xxx.sql

Here root is the mysql root user and password is THIS root user's password.

EXAMPLE: If root user password is hello, database name to export is regdb and xxx.sql is the file where you want to export this regdb, command would be like:

mysqldump -u root -phello --databases regdb > xxx.sql

Note: xxx.sql is the file name where this db will get dumped.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might be one of the last to try/least likely to be the culprit, but this was my problem...

My problem was that the directory I was trying to dump to needed admin privileges to write to and that's what was causing the `mysqldump` command to return `"Access Denied"`.

I set the dump file path to my desktop dir and then it worked.

This was on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  Only occurred after moving from my normal work PC to a PC at a different location.

I had to add my public IP ho address to **Remote MySQL** in my **CPanel** at my host site

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I ran the command in a directory that I didn't have write access to.

Test your access by creating an empty file in the directory, and see if you get an error.

Here was my error

```
mysqldump  -u root librenms -p > librenms.sql
-bash: librenms.sql: Permission denied
```

I changed to my home directory and then it worked.

```
cd ~ 
mysqldump  -u root librenms -p > librenms.sql
Enter password:
```

Do the equivalent on windows,  and it may just fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

**ENSURE YOU TRY REMOVING AND TYPING THE DASH OVER** to make sure that you are actually fighting with the right problem.
Be very careful that you actually have a "-". I apparently had some other character that looks very similar. I had a – instead of a -. I had copied the command from somewhere online don't remember where but the point is I spend a lot of time trying to figure it out when I just needed to replace that character.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Start-> All Programs -> Accessories right click on Command Prompt click on Run as administrator

In the command prompt using CD command Go to MySQL bin folder and run the below command

mysqldump --user root --password=root --all-databases>dumps.sql

it will create dumps.sql file in the bin folder itself.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP already said that they've tried doing that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Running CMD in administrator makes no difference when creating a backup.