# Access denied with correct credentials, what is going on?

Tags: php, mysql

As root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * To 'JKR'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In PHP:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=jkr;charset=utf8", "JKR", "");
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'jkr'' in C:\xampp\www\jkr\core\connect.php:6
```

Only works as root for some reason ...
Also how come I get `Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`?

Comment: JKR'@'%' is the Username and =127.0.0.1;dbname=jkr;charset=utf8" is jkr the Schemaname

Comment: sorry, i have not read all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have an anonymous user `''@'localhost'` on your system. An anonymous user is a user where the name is ignored.

If you connect to MySQL with `JKR` coming from `localhost` it will match you with the anonymous user.

You can check using `SELECT User, Host from mysql.user;`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html for a detailed discussion about the way MySQL matches users and pemissions.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the mysql account was `REQUIRE SSL`; the `ssl_ca` file (at a minimum) had to be provided. Additional ssl parameters are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connection-options.html