# Mysqldump generate empty file in php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I try to save my database in PHP but not work its work only with Shell

With shell (work good)

```
mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost site > C:\xamppp\htdocs\site\sql\tests.sql
```

With php (file is created but empty)

```
system('mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost site > C:\xamppp\htdocs\site\sql\test.sql', $result);
```

for `$result` i have `1`

I work with XAMP on Windows 7, i test `exec` and `system` but its same
Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$return_var = NULL;
$output = NULL;
$command = "mysqldump -u mysql-user -h your_host -pmysql-pass database_name > /directory_path/file.sql";
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

or you can refer to this answer [mysqldump via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679275/mysqldump-via-php)

Comment: Thanks the path with PHP its not correct now its work with `C:\xamppp\mysql\bin\mysqldump`

Answer (score 1):

> Use 2>&1

```
<?php system("mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost site > C:\xamppp\htdocs\site\sql\test.sql 2>&1", $result); ?>
```